# Somewhat confused on the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have the following equation which I require to find the derivative by using the Fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$f(x) = \int_3^{x^2} \left(\frac13t^2-1\right)^{15}dt $$

Trying to understand this, I tried plugging $f(x^2)$ in the formula minus $f(3)$ which was wrong.

Originally, I thought it be $F(x^2)-F(3)$ but I cannot seem to find the anti-derivative.
Can someone help pls ? It's been over a couple years, so I do not remember my derivatives rules by heart, please be clear about those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $$f(x)=\int_3^{x^2}g(t)dt,$$ then $$f'(x)=g(x^2)\cdot 2x,$$ where the $2x$ is from the derivative of $x^2$.

Comment: @Reza M.: Google Leibniz rule to find out what Clayton did. +1

Comment: !!!Thanks, I was doing the anti-derivative of $x^2$ >< Thanks

Comment: @RezaM.: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about the fundamental theorem of calculus is that you don't need to find the anti-derivative in order to differentiate the integral.  Write

$$
f(x)=F(x^2)-F(3)
$$

Then, since $F^\prime=(\frac{1}{3}t^2-1)^{15}$,

$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(F(x^2)-F(3))=\frac{d}{dx}F(x^2)=F^\prime(x^2)\cdot 2x=2x\left(\frac{1}{3}x^4-1\right)^{15}
$$

Notice that $\frac{d}{dx}F(3)=0$ since $F(3)$ will be a constant.

Comment: !!!Thanks, I was doing the anti-derivative of $x^2$ >< Thanks